# how to show items are loading in Recycler view at run time, like Messaging app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have this functionality in my app.

before fetching data from server or database. show a raw view like the picture and after data are present change items view by real data.

what is the best way to do it. does recyclerview supports it internally ?

i need combination of two images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/

Comment: mybe my question was not good . i need this behavior : https://startandroid.ru/images/stories/courses/ArchComp/015/020.gif.pagespeed.ce.EyF3BUY554.gif

Comment: You can do this easily by adding extra items into the list of `recyclerview` and add a condition in your adapter to switch views. To add items you can add a listener to the scrolling of `recyclerview`, then make a network call, then replace those items with the actual data after receiving the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use shimmer view:

https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android

https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93

Create a layout design with it and show/hide based on API call.

Comment: mybe my question was not good . i need this behavior : https://startandroid.ru/images/stories/courses/ArchComp/015/020.gif.pagespeed.ce.EyF3BUY554.gif

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, RecyclerView does not have a native support for this. Overlap two views in a layout (for instance, frame layout) and then show the loading view, load the data, then switch to RecyclerView by setting it visible, and then setting the other views as gone.

Edit: Okay yeah, your question was indeed not good, but I'm gonna try to explain the logic you need to follow, to replicate this exact behavior. You can adjust the requirements as you need.

Think about how a RecyclerView works. It requires an adapter with certain elements in it, right? So, let's say, your network has 100 entries, but you cannot access all of them at once, hence you need to fill your list with "wait" items instead.

I already assume you have a layout with 2 text views side to side, what you need is to have a class with two strings, for example (this is Java btw):

```
public class MyListItem {
    public String item1 = "";
    public String item2 = "";

    public MyListItem(String item1, String item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }
}
```

A list of this class:

`public List<MyListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();`

And, items that are filled with "wait" in them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    items.add(new MyListItem("wait", "wait"));
```

Now that you have your list, create your adapter and attach this list into it, and start fetching the values 5 by 5, then, in your list, **update** these values like:

```
for (int i = lastPosition; i < lastPosition + 5; i++) {

    // This code might throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException,
    // i am not entirely sure but you get the idea.
    items.get(i).item1 = result.get(i - lastPosition).item1;
    items.get(i).item2 = result.get(i - lastPosition).item2;
}
```

and in your adapter call

`myAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, 5);`

where **positionStart** was how many items you already fetched before. The animation from "wait" to "myListItem" will appear once you call the adapter code.

This is the core logic you need to follow, fit it as your requirements and you'll be good to go.

Comment: mybe my question was not good . i need this behavior : https://startandroid.ru/images/stories/courses/ArchComp/015/020.gif.pagespeed.ce.EyF3BUY554.gif

Answer (score 0):

It's called a shimmer effect.

You should implement the below dependency and use it.

> **implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'**

You can refer to the best example to load yours in recycler view data.

Link: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93

GitHub shimmer effect link: https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android